# how to get textview's value from different class in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

In case I have 2 classes, Test_TableViewController and TestCell_TableViewCell.
This is code in class Test_TableViewController

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: TestCell_TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("celltest", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TestCell_TableViewCell

cell.generalcontent()
}
```

This is code in class TestCell_TableViewCell

```
var textarea = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 300, height: 180))
func generalcontent()
{
     self.addSubview(textarea)
}
```

How to get the value in textarea entered by the user in Test_TableViewController class?
Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

One class should not read the UI elements of another class. This indicates that you're breaking the Model-View-Controller architecture that Cocoa relies on. There should be a model object that holds the data you want. You can pass that whole object from your view controller to your cell. The cell can update it if needed as the user modifies the text area, and the view controller will be able to see the changes because they are both looking at the same model object.

For an introduction, see Apple's [Cocoa Core Competencies: Model-View-Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html).

Answer (score 0):

Make the UITextView as a property of TestCell_TableViewCell. Then you can access the UITextView from the Test_TableViewController by using the TestCell_TableViewCell object.

Edit:
You can declare a textview as a variable of the TableViewCell class.

```
var cellTextView:UITextView
```

Then you can access the text value by

```
tableViewCell.cellTextView.text
```

tableViewCell is an object of your class TestCell_TableViewCell.

Comment: Added more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

How about using an ivar to keep a reference to the textarea?

```
var textarea:UITextView?

func generalcontent()
{
     self.textarea = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 300, height: 180))
     self.addSubview(self.textarea)
}
```

Then in `Test_TableViewController` you can get the value by doing:

```
cell.textarea.value
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If `cellForRowAtIndexPath()` is returning a dynamic cell (as your example is), do not add or remove subviews in it, or in any method that it calls.
2. @hAnthony Kong's answer is correct--make the `UITextView` an `@IBOutlet` of the cell, and then your table can access it via the cell.